# When loading html with ajax: should I bring the scripts and css too?

Tags: ajax, jquery-load

I mostly bring JSONs with my ajax requests, but sometimes I do bring HTML snippets.

For example there are these forms I use for creating things in my application: *"create user"*, *"create message"*, etc. I need to reuse them a lot, and I bring them with ajax calls, as opposed to having them preloaded and hidden.

My question is:
**The scripts and css's that give functionality and style to these loaded html's, should be preloaded or should they come with the html as well?**

Example of loaded html:

```
create_message.html
-------------------

<div id="create-message-form">
     ...

    <button id="submit-message">Send</button>
</div>
```

The script that gives functionality to this form needs to set a click-handler to "#submit-message" and other stuff related.

```
create_message.js
------------------

$("#submit-message").click(...);
 ...
```

Should **that** script be pre-loaded or be in the create_message.html snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I would generally tend to pre-load the script, as it makes it so you have to load it only once and simplifies your architecture quite dramatically. Only if it makes speed wise a drastic difference I would consider loading it as needed - but the moment you need to access that part of the system twice you lost your speed gain.

However, if most of your communication is JSON already I would recommend checking out some of the client side templating solutions. This one for example: http://handlebarsjs.com/ or [Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) has a `template` function.

Comment: what about these full ajax sites? like Facebook, in which almost everything is brought by ajax. Would have to preload many many scripts

Comment: @sports I recommend to do a right-click view source on Facebook, I checked out Google and it is designed to pull the immediate content within a split second (it's basically right there in the HTML page) and then pull the rest later. Many sites, wind up using something like requirejs which allows you to compile all your scrips into one in the end, which is quite efficient.